# Set css grid child element's size on the grid, without specifying what column or row it should go into

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

Is it possible do set a div's height and width in amount of rows/columns they should span, without specifying exactly which columns or rows they should go into?

For example, if I have two classes, say `.long` and `.wide`, and I want the `.long` class to be 3 rows high, and 1 column wide, and the `.wide` class be 3 columns wide but only 1 row high.

My specific use case involves Angular 5, I'm dynamically loading in objects and would like to make some of them larger than others. I know I could do this using flexboxes and setting the height, but was curious to see if I could achieve the same (much neater) with a grid, but all I've been finding has every class specified with `grid-column: x/y; grid-row: a/b` and the like.

Comment: The accepted answer here may have what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is an alternative syntax for grid-row and grid-column that sets a **span**:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    border: solid 1px black;
    grid-auto-rows: 30px;
    grid-auto-columns: repeat (5, 50px);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}

.grid div {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.wide {
    grid-column: span 3;
}

.long {
    grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div></div>
<div class="long">LONG</div>
<div class="wide">WIDE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!